# Is there a formula or technique to convert the data with subgroups or same indices into a matrix?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to convert the Left side table

[image]

into the right side table. I currently used some IFs and Filters to get the format. Is there any shortcut as such to make this  conversion faster?

Please refer the image from the hyperlink given.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may try in this way as shown in image below, assuming you are using **O365**,

[image]

• Formula used in cell **D1**

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(A2:A14))
```

• Formula used in cell **D2**

```
=FILTER($B$2:$B$14,D$1=$A$2:$A$14)
```

And Fill Right!